# Specific mysql command

Tags: mysql

Nice to meet you and i hope i can get help here as i tried everything and apparently i cant make it work. I have 3 tables :

```
Clients                                                                 
(
C_ID int NOT NULL,
C_LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
C_FirstName varchar(255),
C_street varchar(255),
C_postcode varchar(255),
C_city varchar(255),
C_DOB date,
C_Phone varchar(255),
C_Email varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (C_Id)
)
```

then

```
Orders 
(
Order_Id int NOT NULL,
Order_date date,
C_Id int,
Employee_Id int,
PRIMARY KEY (Order_Id),
FOREIGN KEY (C_Id) REFERENCES Clients(C_Id),
FOREIGN KEY (Employee_Id) REFERENCES Employee(Employee_Id)
)
```

and the last one

```
Orders_line
(
Order_line_id NOT NULL,
Order_Id int NOT NULL,
Product_Id int,
Order_qty int,
Order_unit_price int,
Order_subtotal int,
Order_grand_total int,
PRIMARY KEY (Order_line_Id),
FOREIGN KEY (Order_Id) REFERENCES Orders(Order_Id),
FOREIGN KEY (Product_Id) REFERENCES Product(Product_Id)
)
```

Question is in my orders_line table I have 3 orders_id which they purchased the same item. The idea is to list all c_id which they bought the common items.

I am very new in this so please have mercy with me :)

My Current attempt

```
SELECT COUNT(c.C_ID), c.c_firstname, c.c_lastname,o.Order_Id 
FROM Clients c, orders_line o 
Where c.C_ID=o.Product_Id
```

And

```
SELECT COUNT(c.C_ID), c.c_firstname , c.c_lastname ,o.Order_Id 
FROM orders c, orders_line o 
Where c.C_ID=o.Product_Id
```

and anything i try is showing me only 1 client with an order id (always order id 1) with different numbers

Comment: Which Database are you using? if you read the sql-server tag it says *" Do not use this tag for other types of DBMS (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle etc.)."*

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are trying to accomplish. Can you show some sample data and expected output?

Comment: who is they? The same person? Different people? Also what if they bought 3 of 5 same items. The question is unclear.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

This looks more like a spec than a question, SO is **not a free coding service** Try to code it yourself, then if you get problems we are more than willing to help, but at least we get a clearer idea what you are trying to do if we see something that nearly works

Comment: Actually the comand i need is to show the clients who was buy the same products

Comment: and the database i am using is phpmyadmin

Comment: __phpMyAdmin__ is not a database, its an application written in PHP that allows you to maintain and manipulate a __MySQL database__

Comment: i am using xamp which have MySQL

Comment: I apologize for how i was write it and also i am not doing this for earning money or something...is my assignment .....till this query i completed 8 of them and this is an module wich have nothing to do with the path i am going(network and telecoms) . So if someone can help is really appreciated and i have tried till now a lot of things..i am stuck on this for over 4 hours.

Comment: SHow us what you have tried so far!

Comment: SELECT COUNT(c.C_ID), c.c_firstname , c.c_lastname ,o.Order_Id
FROM Clients c, orders_line o
<br/>Where c.C_ID=o.Product_Id       <br/>      <br/>          or                      <br/>        SELECT COUNT(c.C_ID), c.c_firstname , c.c_lastname ,o.Order_Id
FROM orders c, orders_line o
Where c.C_ID=o.Product_Id      and anything i try is show me only 1 client with an order id (always order id 1) with diferent numbers      ..

Comment: let us know if you have solved this yet

Comment: Nope.....i have made again the tables ..i identified some mistakes...but still cant get it right

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not entirely sure what you need, but in your WHERE clauses you have `c.C_ID=o.Product_Id`. You don't want to get results where the Customer ID equals the Product ID - that doesn't make sense. You'll need to include the Orders table to join customer and product data.

Something like this would be closer:

`SELECT c.c_firstname, c.c_lastname, o.Order_Id 
FROM Clients c, orders_line ol, orders o
Where c.C_ID=o.C_ID 
and   o.Order_Id = ol.Order_Id`

I recommend writing out samples of your data and what you expect as results, which might help you see more clearly how the data is related.